# Error when calculating focal weight matrix

Tags: r, error-handling

I m trying to calculate the focal weight for a population raster.

```
library(raster)
pop <- raster(ncols=5296, nrows=5296, xmn=-115.9, xmx=-114.041717965, ymn=35.000051298, ymx=36.858333333, crs='+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')
```

I am using the following code

```
fw_1 <- focalWeight(pop, d=c(30), type=c("Gauss"))
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 980.3 Gb
```

I tried fixing the issue by increasing the `memory limit` but it seems that there is still not enough space and the memory limit will not increase any more than what I set it to.

```
memory.limit(size=10000000000000)
```

Also, I am using R 64-bit.

Comment: Can you break up the task to do in smaller processes? The size of this vector is huge, some computers don't even have that much hard drive space.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a matrix of 85498 rows and columns, and you do not have the RAM for 7.3 billion numbers

```
d <- 30 / res(pop)
d[1]
#[1] 85498.32
prod(d)
#[1] 7309963452
```

argument `d` in `focalWeight` is expressed as the radius in the same units as the resolution. You may want to try something like

```
res(pop)[1]
#[1] 0.0003508841

fw_1 <- focalWeight(pop, d=0.0035, type="Gauss")
dim(fw_1)
#[1] 59 59
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked  wonderfully!